# C. Переменная меняется 'сама по себе'

Tags: linux, c, printf

Здравствуйте!

Имеется функция, выделяющая некоторое количество памяти под структуру (с запасом, тема программы - аллокация памяти). В поле структуры осуществляется запись, а далее значение менятся само по себе без видимых на то причин. (см. комментарии к printf)

```
struct mem* new_chunk =
        (struct mem*)mmap(some_aligned_addr, allocated_mem,
             PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
             MAP_FIXED | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS , -1, 0);

if(MAP_FAILED != (long int)new_chunk){

    new_chunk->capacity = 42;

    printf(".new cap \t%lu\n", new_chunk->capacity); // prints 42
    printf(".new cap \t%lu\n", new_chunk->capacity); // prints 43791943968
    printf(".new cap \t%lu\n", new_chunk->capacity); // prints 4121138043265747232
}
```

Структура выглядит так:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct mem{
    struct mem* next;
    size_t capacity;
    bool is_free;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Многопоточность не используется.
Процессор Intel pentium x86-64, под управлением Ubuntu 14.04
 CC = gcc, std=gnu99

В чём же дело?

Comment: Ну так а чему равно `some_aligned_addr`, `allocated_mem`?

Comment: `MAP_FAILED` определяется как значение типа `void *`. Почему и зачем в сравнении `MAP_FAILED != (long int)new_chunk` сделано приведение к типу `(long int)`??? Чтобы в программе стало больше ошибок?

Comment: Передаются через параметры функции

Comment: Прекрасно. Но откуда берутся эти значения и чему они равны?

Comment: Выделяется указанное пользователем количество байт, выравненное по странице:
size_t allocated_mem = size + sizeof(struct mem);
 allocated_mem += (sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE) - allocated_mem % sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)) % sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);

aligned_addr:
(void*)i + i->capacity + sizeof(struct mem)
Где I - некий кусок памяти размеров в n страниц, выделенный mmap'ом

Comment: Почти наверняка ошибка таится в неправильном использовании  флага MAP_FIXED конкретно по адресу, вычисляемому в алгоритме

Comment: не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии к своему вопросу. Отредактируйте его вместо этого, нажмите [edit]

Comment: для вопроса составьте минимальный пример кода, который можно запустить и увидеть проблему. [mcve]

Comment: Вывод разных значений printf явный признак UB где то выше в программе. Адрес чего передают программе на вход ? судя по результатам могу предполжить, что выделенная mmap память располагается поверх стека вашей программы. вот оно и меняется постоянно, потому что при любом вызове функций данные на вершине стека меняются. Как вам вообще удалось получить набор адресов, на который вы можете безбоязненно выполнять mmap, будучи уверенным, что ничего полезного не заденете ?